# Pass Drop Down Selection to Flask/Python Function

Tags: python, flask

I have a working Flask app (relevant portions below) that reads in a .csv file and prints the head of the dataframe to the screen. Additionally, it hard codes the mean over a column in a message to the screen.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request 
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import binom  
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.stats import norm 
from scipy import optimize 
from pyodbc import connect 
import pandas as pd 

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/dataTools', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def data_tools_upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        orig_df = pd.read_csv(request.files.get('file'))
        vars = list(orig_df.columns)
        mean = orig_df[vars[4]].mean()
        dims = orig_df.shape
        message = 'You have data! There are %s rows and %s columns and the variable %s has mean %s' % (dims[0],dims[1],vars[4],round(mean,3))
        table = orig_df.head(10).to_html(classes='data', header = "true")
        return render_template('upload.html', tables = [table], message = message, vars = vars)
    return render_template('upload.html')    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
    # or just app.run()
```

Inside my HTML is the following portion

```
<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <input type=file name=file class = "btn btn-outline-secondary">
    <input type=submit value=Upload class = "btn btn-outline-secondary">
</form>

<select name= vars method="GET" action="/">
    {% for vars in vars %}
    <option value= "{{vars}}" SELECTED>{{vars}}</option>"
    {% endfor %}
</select>
</select>
```

This all "works" in the sense that it displays the content I am hoping for. However, what I'm specifically working towards is the drop down menu currently auto populates with the names of the columns in the data frame. What I want is for the user to choose an option in that drop down and then it would pass to the portion `mean = orig_df[vars[4]].mean()` so that the mean of the variable they choose would be printed.

Thank you for any suggestions.

**UPDATE**

I realize if I want to send information from the HTML back to the server, I need to make a few changes. I am trying the following

```
@app.route('/dataTools', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def data_tools_upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        orig_df = pd.read_csv(request.files.get('file'))
        vars = list(orig_df.columns)
        #mean = orig_df[vars[4]].mean()
        var2use = request.option.get("vars")
        mean = orig_df[var2use].mean()
        dims = orig_df.shape
        message = 'You have data! There are %s rows and %s columns and the variable %s has mean %s' % (dims[0],dims[1],vars[4],round(mean,3))
        table = orig_df.head(10).to_html(classes='data', header = "true")
        return render_template('upload.html', tables = [table], message = message, vars = vars)
    return render_template('upload.html')
```

where I added the portion `var2use = request.option.get("vars")` and then in the HTML I made the following updates so there is also a POST method and the action commuicates back to the function in the flask app.

```
<select name= vars method="GET|POST" action="{{url_for('data_tools_upload')}}">
    {% for var in vars %}
    <option value= "{{var}}" SELECTED>{{var}}</option>"
    {% endfor %}
</select>
</select>
```

I get the following error `AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'option'`.

Hopeful this update helps and also hopeful for a suggested solution.

Comment: `{% for var in vars %}`, change vars to var  and `value="{{ var }}" SELECTED>{{var}}</option>"`

Comment: Thank you. Change made as suggested. Is there a corresponding change to `mean = orig_df[vars[4]].mean()` that needs to be made so that the variable chosen from the drop down passes to this line?